# lldb linux - Not recognized engine using "/usr/bin/lldb"

Tags: llvm, qt-creator, lldb, clang++

I'm trying to set lldb as the debugger in a Qt Creator kit on Debian Jessie. But got:

```
Not recognized engine using "/usr/bin/lldb"
```

What might be going on?

I got clang and lldb via apt-get.

Comment: lldb is a debugger, are you following the documentation here? http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html#setting-up-experimental-lldb-support

Comment: I don't know about Jesse's LLVM packages, but some of the Ubuntu LLVM packages would create files such as "/usr/bin/lldb-3.8" but not "/usr/bin/lldb".  You may want to confirm that you actually have a "/usr/bin/lldb" on your system.